# using delete[] on non-array variable in c++

Tags: c++

This may sound a bit strange, but if I have the code uses delete []  as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int *test = new int(5);
    delete [] test //Does this work?
    // delete test (This is the standard syntax)
}
```

Of course, I tried to compile and run, and delete [] didn't return any errors. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/, delete[] operator first calls the appropriate destructors for each element in the array (if these are of a class type), and then calls an array deallocation function. I'm not 100% sure what array deallocation function is, but I presume this will not cause memory leak?

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Comment: A flaw in this specific test is that - on some compilers - `delete` and `delete[]` just happens to generate the same code for `int`s, but different code for class types with destructors. Makes it hard to test for UB.

Answer (score 4):

Running `delete []` for a pointer which was allocated with `new` is an [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). It may work, or may not, or may stop working at any moment, or may ruin your hardware. You have no guarantee.